# Does returning VFW_S_CANT_CUE from IMediaFilter::GetState have any negative consequences

Tags: directshow

This MSDN page describes the need for some filters to return VFW_S_CANT_CUE from GetState() in the paused state if there's a possibility that the filter can't deliver while paused. That all seems clear enough. It seems if there's any doubt for a particular then it's probably better to return VFW_S_CANT_CUE to make sure that Pause() doesn't hang.

[Delivering Samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375433(v=vs.85).aspx)

Are there any downsides to returning VFW_S_CANT_CUE though? Is resuming streaming from the paused state likely to perform poorly or lose sync if a mux or demux filter in the graph returns VFW_S_CANT_CUE?

I've inherited source code for several filters that sometimes return VFW_S_CANT_CUE for reasons that aren't clear to me (for example only returning VFW_S_CANT_CUE if no output samples have been delivered). I'm wondering if there any risks from always returning VFW_S_CANT_CUE.

Answer (score 0):

Return of `VFW_S_CANT_CUE` disables synchronization with renderers during stopped/paused transition: Filter Graph Manager is not waiting for renderers to report that they are ready, which in case of video renderer means that it receives a banner frame and presents it (I suppose with sending `EC_PAUSED` notification). Disabled synchronization means that `IMediaControl::Pause` returns immediately and does not wait for banner frame, what live sources might prefer to do.

The only downside I can think of is that having `Pause` call completed you cannot be sure that video renderer presents valid frame and not blackness instead. I suppose the unclear reasoning behind `VFW_S_CANT_CUE` you are seeing is attempts of the developer to avoid deadlocks he stumbled on during debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If filter returns `VFW_S_CANT_CUE` in `GetState()` method (i.e. **LiveSource**), `Pause()` method will not wait for samples to be queued. And because of this, **stream time** startd when filter graph is started.
Otherwise, filter graph will wait until several samples have been queued. And only after that **stream time** will be started (because after `Pause()`, `Run()` method called)